# In C, how can we use pointers in place of array to change case and print the length?

Tags: c

I am writing a program to convert the lower case sentence into upper case. I also want the length of the string. I am doing it by (both) arrays and pointers. The program is as follows:-

```
/* Program to convert the lower case sentence in upper case sentence and also calculate the length of the string */
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char fac='a'-'A',ch[20],*ptr,a[20];int i=0,count=0;
    ptr=ch;

    /* Changing case and printing length by using pointers */
    printf("Enter the required string");
    gets(ptr);
    while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        *ptr+=fac;   // LINE #1
        ptr++;
        count++;
    }
    puts(ptr);
    printf("%d",count);

    /* Changing case by using arrays */
    printf("Enter the required string");
    gets(ch);
    while(ch[i]!='\0')
    {
        ch[i]+=fac;
        i++;
    }
    puts(ch);
return 0;
}
```

This program is working perfectly for printing the length ( in the pointer part ) and changing the case ( in the array part).The problem is case-conversion by pointers. I am under impression that LINE#1 increments the value stored at the pointer "ptr" by the required number ( 32 ). But nothing is happening on the screen. Why is this happening? Please help.

Comment: you need to make a copy of original ptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your loop:

```
while(*ptr!='\0')
{
    ...
    ptr++;
    ...
}
puts(ptr);
```

You've incremented `ptr` until its value is the address of the nul terminator! So all you're printing is an empty string.

Instead, store the initial value of `ptr` somewhere before the loop:

```
char *initial_ptr;
...
initial_ptr = ptr;
while(*ptr!='\0')
{
    ...
    ptr++;
    ...
}
puts(initial_ptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You increment ptr to the end of the string in the loop and then you print out the string using ptr - which is at end of string so you get nothing.  Change it to puts(ch) and I think it will work.  Oh yeah - I think you want -= not += for lower to upper case conversion.

BTW, before incrementing, you might want to make sure the character is in the correct input range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. But I am not able to understand your logic _**and then you print out the string using ptr - which is at end of string so you get nothing**_. I copied the value of ch into ptr at the beginning only. Also, I am storing values in indivivual addresses. So, why is this a problem?

Comment: But in the loop your ptr++ operation changes the value of ptr.

Comment: Just replace ptr by ch in puts(ptr);

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is pointing to a memory address.  You need to read the character at the address, not the address itself.  Of course, if you change the case of a char variable created via pointer, you will change the actual character in the memory.  If this is not what you want, you'll need to create a temp char array or string.